# Load Google Analytics Conditionally

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I need to filter internal QA people out of our analytics reporting.

We currently have code in our site that shows/hides an information div if the visitor is of the 'student' role:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($.inArray('student',ENV['current_user_roles']) === 1 && $.inArray('student',ENV['current_user_roles']) === 1 ){
  if ($.inArray('teacher',ENV['current_user_roles']) == -1 ){
  paramArray = window.location.href.split('/');
  if (paramArray.indexOf('assignments') == -1 && paramArray.indexOf('settings') == -1 && paramArray.indexOf('grades') == -1 && paramArray.indexOf('quizzes') == -1  && paramArray.indexOf('users') == -1){ 
    var l = $('#right-side-wrapper a.edit_link.button.button-sidebar-wide'); 
    if(l===null || l.length===0){
      $('body').removeClass('with-right-side');
    }
  }
}
} 
});
```

I am not well-versed in JavaScript, but it seems like there should be a simple way to re-use this code, but wrap the google analytics tracking code inside, and only load it if the user is of the role 'student:'

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($.inArray('student',ENV['current_user_roles']) === 1 && $.inArray('student',ENV['current_user_roles']) === 1 ){
  if ($.inArray('teacher',ENV['current_user_roles']) == -1 ){
    var _gaq=[["_setAccount","UA-xxxxxxxx-1"],["_trackPageview"]];
    (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.async=1;
    g.src=("https:"==location.protocol?"//ssl":"//www")+".google-analytics.com/ga.js";
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,"script"));
}
} 
});
```

I tried the above, based on what I saw around the internet [ https://gist.github.com/benbalter/902140 ], but this implementation did not successfully filter out non-students.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your code is that `_gaq` is going to be a local variable, and different from the `_gaq` object that's loaded by ga.js.  Because the `_setAccount` & `_trackPageview` weren't in the global `_gaq`, nothing should have been tracked.

Is there another set of analytics code anywhere in the page?

Suggestions:

- Put the code to load Google Analytics in the page header, but leave out the `_setAccount` & `_trackPageview` parts.
- On page load, conditionally push `_setAccount` & `_trackPageview` commands.

In the page header, something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

And on page load

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($.inArray('student',ENV['current_user_roles']) === 1){
    _gaq.push("_setAccount","UA-xxxxxxxx-1");
    _gaq.push("_trackPageview");
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use Cookies. Simple set a cookies on your QA workstation and if cookie is set, the Google code is not call.